# How do I stop Py_Initialise crashing the application?

Tags: c++, python, excel, vba, vb6

From VBA and VB6 I'm calling a dll the creates a Python interpreter. If I set the `PATH` environment variable to point to `"C:\python27"` and `PYTHONPATH` to `"c:\python27\lib"` all is fine.

If I don't set the `PATH` then calling `Py_Initialise()` crashes XL or my VB6 app, even if I call `Py_SetProgramName` with `"c:\python27\python27.exe"` first.

I'd like to specify the installation in VB/VBA rather than having it set in the environment as I can't do that in XL (works ok for VB6).

Comment: Even someway to check if the configuration works would be good. Worst case I can set the env vars using getenv or GetEvvironmentVariable (I'm on windows). I'd like to link to the install copy of python and not blow up excel or any other embedder of python.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I've found so far is that it is a bug in Python - http://bugs.python.org/issue6498. The intepreter seems to call exit() on certain errors rather than passing a code back to the caller. Not very friendly if you're embedding python in an app. But there you go.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the working directory before calling the dll:

In your VBA code:

```
chdir("c:\python27\") '- change the working-directory for python
=> call dll '- call the dll
chdir(app.Path) '- change back to your folder (maybe you want to save your current folder bevore you change it the first time and change back to this?!)
```

regards Thomas

Comment: Doesn't really address the issue of Py_Initialise crashing the app.

Comment: Worse, ties the program to Windows machines with Python 2.7 installed in the standard location on harddisk C.

Comment: the app is crashing because [Py_Initialise] does not found some folder or file?! so if you change to the folder where [Py_Initialise] search for the files/folders it will not crash - hopefully. [larsmans] I use this path because it is mentioned in the question...?! this answer only gives the rough idea what you have to do.

Comment: @Thomas, whilst that might be good advice it doesn't answer the question. As indicated in my question I can get the setup right. I'm trying to figure out how to stop Py_Initialize from terminating a host process if the setup isn't right - I'd prefer a nice dialog box telling the user of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the needed environment variable is set:

```
dim PPath as string
PPath = trim(Environ("PYTHONPATH"))
if (PPath<>"")
  <call dll>
else
  msgbox ("Error!")
end if
```

Or you can run the dll in a nother Test-Process: if this call works you know that it is OK to call the dll - it depends on the DLL call your using so I'm not sure about that:

```
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
    dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As _
    Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long

Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103
Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF

...
dim IsActive as boolean
dim Handle as long
Dim TaskID As Long
TaskID = Shell("rundll32.exe pyton.dll Py_Initialise()", vbNormalNoFocus)

<wait for some time>

'- check if pyton.dll is still running
Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, TaskID)
Call GetExitCodeProcess(Handle, ExitCode)
Call CloseHandle(Handle)

IsActive = IIf(ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE, True, False)

if (not IsActive) then
  msgbox ("Error!")
else
  <kill process>
  <call dll normally>
end if
```

Regards Thomas

Comment: Yup. I was considering running a test process to see if the setup is ok. Not really keen on it but if there is no other way to prevent Py_Initialise crashing its host then that may be the answer. Thx.